# Right place to garbage collect File type in dispose pattern

Tags: c#, dispose, unmanaged

now there is a debate between my coworkers regarding where the C# File type needs to be handled. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose)

Looking at the code below, currently File.Delete is within if(disposing) section, where it is considered for managed objects.  Some people believe it needs to be outside of the loop and need to be place for unmanaged objects.

```
~someService() => Dispose(false);

public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    GC.Collect();
}

bool disposed = false;
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposed)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (disposing)
    {
        // Dispose managed state (managed objects).
        tempFilePaths?.ToList().ForEach(f =>
        {
            if (File.Exists(f))
            {
                File.Delete(f);
            }
        });

        this._engine?.Dispose();
    }

    // TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override a finalizer below.
    // TODO: set large fields to null.
    this._fields = null;

    disposed = true;
}
```

Comment: It comes down to that when the object isn’t explicitly disposed and object is not used anymore and the GC calls the finalizer if the file should be deleted or not. If it should be deleted in any case then put it outside the if block. However, finalizer should avoid doing heavy work as the GC is single-threaded and a slow finalizer will slow down the GC’s work. Another issue is that you should never call `GC.Collect`. Let the GC handle the cleaning when it has time.

Comment: but on the other side, I don't want to see ObjectDisposedException by putting managed objects outside of the if(disposing). And if the memory needs to be freed quick, GC.Collect seems necessary so I want to know strong reasoning on why it should never be called. thanks.

Comment: Why does the memory need to be collected quickly? The GC will automatically collect it when the memory pressure is high. Garbage Collecting is expensive. So triggering it any time such an object is disposed and not just for freeing the object itself but for all unneeded objects of a process may have negative impacts on the applications performance. Also it violates the single responsibility principle as an ExtractionService should not concern itself with a processes memory management.

Comment: It's indeed application specific but the problem with current design is that the memory allocated for this previous task can indeed block the next task from completing the job due to at-once coming in of data can cause huge memory occupied and needs to be removed. But let me search more on the side effect of GC.Collect, thanks.

Comment: I would say that you should not delete files inside the finalizer, cause it can negatively affect performance of your app, and finalizer should be quick so it definitely should not be performed during finalization. But if for some reason `Dispose` is not called file will not get deleted. But you can't rely on finalizer either, so I think the best approach would to delete files in `Dispose(true)` and have back up strategy for extraordinary cases(for example perform clean up on start of your app if you guaranteed to have only one app instance running).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should Dispose() or Finalize() be used to delete temporary files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240968/should-dispose-or-finalize-be-used-to-delete-temporary-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just read carefully about the `IDisposable` pattern to understand what these "sections" mean and when they will be executed.

**TL;DR**
You don't use *any* existing references to managed objects outside of the `if (disposing)` block. In your example, `tempFilePaths` seems to be a field/property of the `IEnumerable<string>` type which *is* a managed object (an existing reference). So, the only correct place to access/use it is inside of the `if (disposing)` block.

**Reason**
The code outside of `if (disposing)` runs *both* on calling the public `Dispose()` method and when called by the finalizer.

The finalizer will be called on a special finalizer thread. It is not guaranteed that - at the time of the finalizer call - the `tempFilePaths` will be available at all. It could have been collected by the GC already, despite the object reference is held by your class instance. This is how the finalzers work.

If you want more background and more arguments while discussing with your team, please carefully read these blog posts by Eric Lippert (former C# compiler team member) about the finalizers:

[When everything you know is wrong, part one](https://ericlippert.com/2015/05/18/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-one/)
[When everything you know is wrong, part two](https://ericlippert.com/2015/05/21/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-two/)

Comment: OP wants to delete files, he does not dispose the `tempFilePaths`

Comment: @GuruStron, the OP **accesses** the `tempFilePaths` collection which is already dangerous. It doesn't matter what happens with the collection contents. Simply accessing a dead object might lead to a finalizer crash (and the OS will kill the application instantly).

Comment: Yes. Still if `Dispose` is not called the issue with not cleared files remains.

Comment: That is true. But using `Dispose` to clean up non-disposable resources is an incorrect design.

Comment: @dymanoid, which resource are you refering to as non-disposable resources?  And if Dispose is not right place, where should the code be written to clean up the non-disposable resources?

Comment: @swcraft Your original question is about where to place a particular code in a `Dispose` method. Non-disposable resource is a collection of strings: `tempFilePaths`.Your question about the clean-up is a different one, so please ask it as a separate question.

Comment: Thanks for the links; I made a minor correction. I was never at architect level at Microsoft; I was "principal engineer" when I left, which sounds higher up than it is. :)